# For Apache IoTDB service deployed by docker, how to modify to only print specific type of log information?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

For the cluster version of Apache IoTDB deployed by docker, I want to know which configuration parameter I can modify to change the level of log records, to make it only print exceptions and warnings. If there are no parameter that can directly do this (which should be the case since I find nothing on the official guide), then I want to know are there any other ways for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache IoTDB does not have special processing of log record level, so if you want to modify them, you need to map the configuration file. There are `logback-confignode.xml` and `logback-datanode.xml` in the `conf` directory of IoTDB. You need to modify the corresponding default settings (which reported all errors) and then restart the system.